# The best way to get unique value in array inside array using filter JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I using array inside array like the example below 
the left element is user Id and the right element is a timestamp value

```
[[2222,2344556], [1111,2344546], [1111,2345556], [1111,2347556]]
```

I'm trying to do the following :

1. filter users with more than 60 sec, to do so I used this code and it working well

   ```
   recived_msg_user.filter(([user, date]) => Math.abs(date - nowTimeStamp) < 60000
   ```
2. Now I'm trying to add a filter for showing uniqueness users **with the recent timestamp**

   ```
   [[2222,2344556], [1111,2347556]]
   ```

How to do so? there is an option to do it in the same filter?

Answer (score 1):

Here is some low level bubbling with exclusion. Should be speedy enough.

```
function filter(array) {
    let filtered = [];
    let checkedIndexes = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (!(Math.abs(item[1] - nowTimeStamp) < 60000) ||
                                 checkedIndexes.includes(i)) continue;
        let index = i;
        let time = array[i][1];
        for (let j = i + 1; j < array.length; j++) {
            if (array[j][0] == array[i][0]) {
                checkedIndexes.push(j);
                if (array[j][1] > time) {
                    index = j;
                    time = array[j][1];
                }
            }
        }
        filtered.push(array[index]);
    }
    return filtered;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In terms of being in the same filter, I'm not sure if there is an option to do that. However, on a separate line you can use the array method of `sort` then sort by the lowest timestamp. Here's the code

```
yourArray.sort((a, b) => a[1] - b[1]);
```

Should change the array to order everything by the lowest timestamp to the greatest timestamp. I hope this helps.

Comment: What do you mean by unique users, users with different Ids or users with special Ids or something else?

Comment: every user-id  should show only one time in the result include his latest timestamp

Comment: Ah I see, so keep the user ids with the latest timestamp and remove the other same user ids

Comment: Yes, this is the second part